# Accessing pig logs on HDInsight

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

How do I access pig log files on HDInsight?

When pig errors the output says:

```
Details at logfile: C:\apps\dist\hadoop-1.2.0.1.3.7.1-01293\logs\pig_1399635949926.log
```

I can't find anything like that in the blob store and I have no idea how to access that path.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It is because it exists on the C:\ drive of the headnode. Simple steps to access it:

1. Go the [manage.windowsazure.com](http://manage.windowsazure.com) and go to your HDI cluster
2. Enable remote access, choose a user and a password (note admin is reserved)
3. Then just login the machine
4. Open the explorer and go to that path
5. Either copy&paste to your local machine or open it in notepad

Comment: Thanks, but it's all gone tits-up :-(  I went to that path but pig_blah.log didn't exist and now when I run Start-AzureHDInsightJob I get `Request failed with code:Unauthorized`.  I added -Credential with no effect.

Comment: I'm disabling remote access...  will try again with something else.

Comment: Ok, was able to undo all that.  Trouble is the only files in the logs folder are hadoop--copyFromLocal-HEADNODE0.log
hadoop--mkdir-HEADNODE0.log
hadoop--put-HEADNODE0.log
hadoop--rmr-HEADNODE0.log
hadoop--test-HEADNODE0.log
hadoop.log
which are all zero bytes

Comment: When running a Pig job via Start-AzureHDInsightJob, the script is going to actually execute on a worker node.  If you can find where the single map task from the Templeton (WebHCat) controller job ran, that will tell you which worker node will have the logs local on the C:.  You can RDP to the worker node (like workernode0) from the headnode.  Many _other_ logs are aggregated into Azure Table Storage (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2014/01/06/accessing-hadoop-logs-in-hdinsight.aspx) but it doesn't look like the pig log is making it into there.